# Can IBM cloud's free kubernetes cluster run multiple containers?

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-kubernetes, iks

I am new to kubernetes. I have IBM free kubernetes cluster. I deployed image. Seems running fine. So i was wondering: is it meant to run just one container? Is that the same as deployment? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, IBM Cloud's free tier can run multiple containers. You are restricted to just a single node but that is capable of running multiple pods and each pod can then have multiple containers within it.